# How to increase the operating speed of a solenoid?

Tags: power, solenoid, speed

I'm working on a prototype of a small electric appliance. The part I need help with is a small box in which the floor needs to move up and down quickly to repeatedly bounce an object against the top (approximately 60 times per 30 seconds). I've built the box out of plexiglass, and it's approximately 1 1/2 inches wide, by 2 inches long by 4 inches tall.

The solenoid I'm currently using is rated at 12 V DC, 2.5 A with 15mm travel and 45 N force. I'm powering it with an adapter with the same rating. The object in question (it's about the size and weight of an unshelled almond) is not striking the top of the box hard enough.

I think it needs to move faster. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the physics of energy conversion? from watt-seconds to kinetic 1/2mv² minus heat loss?

Comment: try a more powerful solenoid?, the platform weight can be reduced with a spring then use a push pull drive current to increase kinetic energy from additional energy stored in the compressed spring, which may require a longer box.

Comment: Hi Tony, I only understand the physics in broad concepts; I'm not familiar with the formula or what a  watt-second equates to. Is it one over two times mass times velocity squared? I'm looking at more powerful solenoids, but I don't know if they will move faster, or just push more weight. I started with a smaller unit, and it was too weak. The platform is fairly light, comparable to a nickle or quarter, but the reset spring IS pushing the armature downward. I have thought about removing it. I don't know how to switch from push to pull, when I reverse the leads it goes the same way.

Comment: some Push solenoids lose force past the half stroke length and many are not rated for continuous duty for thermal reasons.  It seems your solenoid is the AC/DC push type.  This is a 100W unit https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/ROB-10391/ROB-10391-ND/6163693

Comment: Consider a voice coil instead of a solenoid

Comment: Besides turn-on speed, if you find that you need to speed up turn-off, this is often done by adding a zener or TVS diode in series with the flyback diode to hold an opposing voltage to help the current decay more quickly. This is also sometimes done with a resistor in series with the flyback diode, although a little less effective since the opposing voltage decays with the current.

Comment: * The part I need help with is a small box in which the floor needs to move up and down quickly to repeatedly bounce an object against the top*... How are you dealing with the air inside the box?

Comment: I have a second, smaller, box (of 1/8" acrylic sheet) that the solenoid pushes up. It's approximately 1 inch by 1 3/4 inches by 1/2 inch tall. I drilled  28, 1/8 inch holes in the top, and 12, 1/4 inch holes in the sides to reduce weight and drag. On the bottom, I cut triangles out, leaving struts to each corner, and the middle of each edge (it looks rather similar to the British flag).

Answer (score 4):

You can drive the solenoid from a higher voltage than its rated 12 V to bring it in with greater force and therefore more abruptly.

The solenoid will produce an increasingly strong magnetic field as the core is pulled in, as it gives the inductor an iron/steel former instead of an air former. So, once it's pulled in, you can reduce the solenoid drive voltage back to your 12 V to hold it in place.

One way is using a switched supply/regulator in your drive circuit to produce a higher voltage. However, you will have to ensure your drive circuit has no failure mode that continually drives the solenoid from this higher voltage. Depending on your application, this can burn the solenoid out or even cause a fire, so it represents an electrical safety hazard.

I had an application using several solenoids that required sharp pull-in and on for only a short duty cycle of a machine's operation (0.5 sec or so every 1.5 secs).

The solution I used was to charge a large capacitor when the solenoid was off then dump its current into the solenoid when energised. The profile of the capacitor discharging into the solenoid nicely covered the time to pull the solenoid in and gave it a sharp action. It was very reliable and we made a large number of them. We had tight cost constraints but, more importantly, the circuit would have to be safe under Single Point Of Failure (SPOF) conditions (any component short or open circuit) to meet safety approvals. My circuit met that, as once the capacitor's discharged, there's nothing to overvolt the solenoid with. The current requirements could be handled by our existing PSU because the capacitors were charged while the solenoids were off, unlike a higher-voltage PSU approach.

(Excuse the rough'n'ready schematic)

[image: Solenoid driver with sharp pull-in]

When Q is off, the solenoid coil pulls drain/detect voltage Vd to near-Vss via supply diode Ds. Vd is higher than threshold voltage Vth so the power op-amp output goes low and C charges to near-Vss through charge diode and resistor Dc and Rc. Pulse diode Dp is reverse-biased and passes no current.

When Q is turned on, Vd is pulled to GND and the op-amp output goes to near-Vss. The capacitor is already charged to near-Vss so the Rc/Dp junction goes to (2 x near-Vss). Dc is reverse-biased which protects Vss from this doubled voltage. Capacitor current flows through Dp into the solenoid. Ds is also reverse-biased which protects Vss again. When C is discharged, the normal operating solenoid current is drawn through Ds.

Here, 'near-Vss' means Vss minus a diode drop, op-amp output drop etc.

The exact capacitor value depends upon the solenoid and time is needed to recharge it during the solenoid off-time. I used 470 uF but in guessland I'd start with 100 uF then try 220 uF with your solenoids. Trial and error in the real system under real mechanical loads was the quick and pragmatic way to choose our capacitor values, our loads had springs and all sorts.

Charging resistor Rc can be calculated from the standard capacitor charging equation to ensure it can charge the capacitor in time from a practical resistor value. By practical, I mean an Rc the PSU can supply the initial C charging current for (something like 11/Rc amps) and of a suitable power rating. For ours, this meant a 5 W resistor. I used 1N4001 for all diodes.

Note that I used a power op-amp back then but you may well favour a FET-based H-bridge driver. I showed the op-amp because it also illustrates the control signalling, which will be different with a different driver.

Comment: Hello TonyM, I would like to understand your circuit but I am struggling; would you oblige to help explain it to me? I determined that the op-amp is in an "op-amp buffer/follower orientation" and I am familiar with the low side driver topology bottom right. Does the op-amp output charge the capacitor? Is the initial voltage across the capacitor the same as the voltage from the top rail to the bottom rail? Is the bottom rail grounded? Can I assume the top and bottom rails are, for example, +12VDC and ground?; does the op-amp use the same supply rails?

Comment: Hi @Mike, clarified as requested.

Comment: Hi Tony, I am trying to simulate this in LTspice https://imgur.com/a/w0IJACJ; can I post a new question with the sim details and scope plots? Is there a way to tag you in my question? I am using 12vds for the Vss rail and when Q is turned on I do see the jump to 24V at the Rc/Dp junction but is is instantaneously zeroed no matter what values i assign to the resistors, capacitors etc.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I've set up a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135074/chat-between-tonym-and-mike) for us rather than you posting a question, thanks. Am sure we'll get through it quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe how you are switching the power to the solenoid.  With a relay?  Are you switching the AC going into the adapter, or do you use a switching device (relay, transistor) between the power adapter and the solenoid? In the process of closing the solenoid wants to draw a surge of current, and to speed it up you need to either supply more voltage or supply enough current so that the voltage doesn't sag during the surge.  Do you have the ability to measure the current during the event with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Hi electrogas, Right now I'm just crossing the bare leads to power the solenoid. I haven't picked up a momentary switch yet. I'm plugging the power adapter into a power strip that goes straight to a wall outlet in my house, no relays, switches or transistors. To supply more voltage, can I simply use a 24V adapter at the same amperage, or does the amperage have to increase as well? Will this damage the solenoid, or cause it to overheat? I have a (low end) multi-meter, but no oscilloscope.

Comment: using 24 volts could overheat the solenoid if left on for any length of time. For short bursts it would be ok.

Comment: you could do an experiment to see if your 12 volt supply is not able to supply the surge current.  You could put a large electrolytic capacitor across the supply to provide the surge.  Or perhaps substitute a 12 volt source such as a car battery that can provide a much larger surge.  Be very careful with a setup like that to not short out the battery though - lest you start a fire or burn yourself.

Comment: I connected three adapters, and a battery charger to the solenoid, with a combined output of approximately 48V and 12A. It was enough to accomplish the work I needed, but I'm not having any luck finding an affordable adapter with that output. Is it necessary to increase Volts AND Amps to speed up the solenoid?

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATIVES**

I am not at all convinced your current solenoid is right for this application.

You need fast acceleration in the up direction. Since solenoids rely on a spring to return them to their initial state, (Or gravity...but you can not adjust that), you could reduce that spring strength. However that means the solenoid may not return to the rest state before the next cycle and will end up "resting" somewhere close to the UP position.

Speaking of the springs. If you are raising the floor inside a box, you need to pay attention to where the air is going to go. The air itself will act as a very effective spring if it can not easily move to and from either side of the "floor".

You can, and should, try an activation voltage boosting technique to give you faster initial acceleration. TonyM's solution is a good one.

If all that fails, the alternative is to make it a stronger magnet. You can not over-driving the solenoid by adding more current, that may cook the coil, especially inside a closed box.

So.. if the current device is too small that means you may need a bigger, stronger solenoid, and probably a bigger box.

However the issue with solenoids is the spring. A push-pull device, like a permanent magnet "voice coil" type linear actuator, would be more efficient. But those get costly. I looked a few up, but when it says "Request A Quote", I take that as code for... "If you have to ask, you can't afford it". However, if you are planning on making thousands of this product, a custom voice-coil, made over-seas, may be cost effective.

[image]

Since your stroke length is short, it may also be suitable to use a simple and relatively cheap motor driven rotary cam.

[image]

Comment: You surprise me. Solenoids are perfectly capable of such a rate as 60 times for 30 seconds. And consider just how many solenoids have been put into machines over the last 60-odd years and worked hard over a long life. No spring will be needed, not even 'really' in capitals, if the load or gravity returns it. No coil will be cooked otherwise solenoids wouldn't have a market. You seem to have gone off at an odd tangent, trying to redesign the OP's unknown system. Don't mind me asking but have you just not worked on electromechanical designs with solenoids?

Comment: @TonyM yes I have. That is how I know that return motion is dependent on a spring (or gravity), return **time** is dependent on the spring force and the inertia of whatever is to be moved. If you are moving **any appreciable mass**, you need a large spring, which in turn means you need a bigger magnet to pull that spring, which means more current... and round you go. The OP never mentioned his mass though, hence I phrased it as a doubt.

Comment: @TonyM, Continued: Though I have a sneaking suspicion the OPs issue may not be mass, but air compression. "Rising floor inside a box.."

Comment: Sorry, Trevor, but that sounds like science over experience. At the other end of the scale, look at the treatment they got in pinball machines for years off finger triggers. In the middle, we had them in larger office and industrial equipment for many many years with nothing like what you describe seen by a large service team over a lot of export countries - nothing like it. Thanks for your polite reply.

Comment: @TonyM, I'm not saying it's not possible, I know full well it is.  I'm saying it may not be possible in a box that small at a cost he can justify for his product.

Comment: But you describe it very very dramatically as high risk and likely to fail quickly. Incidentally, we don't know if it's a product or a home toy, could be in his shed with no equipment or on a £2 budget for 50Mpa manufacture. And a solenoid will be cheaper than an eccentric cam motor or suchlike. We must answer the question or ask for detail rather than reimagine. You must see that you've gone off wildly, answering your question not theirs? I admire your enthusiasm but not the aptness :-)

Comment: @TonyM, where exactly did I describe it "very very dramatically as high risk and likely to fail quickly" The OP wants to drive an undersized solenoid harder inside a confined space. That will likely cook it. Clearly you are reading more into my words than is intended. Nothing I can do about that.

Comment: Here: "More likely it will simply throw out and then vibrate against the end stop. It would need to have a REALLY strong return spring, and therefor need large current to drive it. Either that or it would be too small to do any useful work. In the mean time you would probably cook the coil." Pretty full-on stuff :-) But it sounds like you're not taking to an outsider's pov, or mine anyway, so I'll leave it there and wish you well.

Comment: @TonyM, Not at all. I am listening with interest. As with all written correspondence, what gets written is not always totally what is meant, or what is received by the reader. I'm currently evaluating my answer to better explain what I meant. Thank you for your feedback, I appreciate the different viewpoint. Have a great day,

Comment: Thank you both, Tony and Trevor. I find the lively exchange of ideas delightful.  I very much appreciate the suggestion of a motor driven cam, and would like to see how the connections work. In my second attempt at a proof of concept model, I used drawer slides mounted in a rectangular box to move a platform up and down. Using small bearings from casters and scooters, I connected a push rod to a lever that I spun with a drill, which worked, but had too much power.  I do plan to make thousands of these, (or license them) so cost will be a factor. I described how I reduced the air drag above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something mechanical. For example, pull the solenoid back against a spring and then reverse the current so you have the additional energy of the spring being released