# Charge pump as a solenoid driver

Tags: solenoid, charge-pump

I have a solenoid valve, and the datasheet claims response times as low as 165 µs. I have driven the valve at its rated voltage (28 V) and am only able to get response times of ~3 ms.

The company that makes the valve also sells a driver, but they run about $10k, and we would need 5 of them for our project, so we don't want to spend that much money. The company's driver puts out a spike of 275 V (checked with a scope), pulsed for up to 500 µs (configurable). The valve functions, with a response time of ~250 µs, which is acceptable for the use case we have.

I'm not quite sure how they generate the 275 V, and I am unable to fully remove the board from the driver to completely reverse engineer it. There are some MOSFET's and capacitors on the board that I am unsure of what they're doing, so it might be possible they're using a charge pump to create that high voltage.

So my questions are:

1. Is it unreasonable to hit the valve with 275 V to get the response time needed?
2. What is the math behind why hitting the valve with a higher voltage gets it to open faster?
3. Is a charge pump a reasonable way to create this voltage?
4. Are there any suggestions for a controller to make this easier, if a charge pump is reasonable?

Scope capture from the company driver, differential probe 100:1, with the probes attached in parallel with the valve:

[image: Scope capture].

Channel 1 is the control signal.

Valve information: Rated voltage 28 V, 70 Ω + 135 mH (@1 kHz).

Driver PCB:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The higher voltage causes the current through the solenoid's inductance to rise much faster. It's likely they're using a boost converter - check if there are any inductors or transformers nearby on the board.

Comment: @JonathanS. There is a large transformer on the board, as well as a discrete full bridge rectifier, but as far as I can tell, they're not connected directly to the valve. I personally figure they're used to power the timing section of the board.

Edit: I'd also like to ideally avoid using a transformer for physical size restrictions, but if it's the most practical way it the customer should be able to handle it.

Comment: Check the output voltage after the rectifier. Also, look for electrolytic capacitors with a high voltage rating (300V+). If you're allowed to show a picture of the board, please do.

Comment: @JonathanS. Edited post to include imgur link to PCB photos.

Comment: Just to rule it out, since 275 V is very close to 1/10 of 28 V rated, are you sure the scope is not set for 10 X with 100 X probe?

Comment: @winny yes 100% sure. We tested with both a 10:1 passive probe and saw similar voltages to using the 100:1 active probe. You can also see that the scope is set to 100:1 on the right hand side.

Comment: Good. Just wanted to check.

Comment: From the pictures, it seems like the control unit just generates the 275V with that huge mains transformer and a diode bridge, then slaps that voltage onto the valve's solenoid with an IRF840 MOSFET, which can handle 500V. No flyback or charge pump involved.

Comment: For reference, have a look at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/295529/115257). It details how I overvolted solenoids to pull them in quicker using a voltage doubler, so lower voltage than your plan, but please do note the safety and approvals text.

Comment: @TonyM I actually looked at that design once we realized that we needed the super high voltage, and I considered prototyping it as a proof of concept. We do have similar safety concerns, with the added issue that any failure mode needs to have the valve remain closed (otherwise it will overload a $30k diffusion pump). 

Do you have any idea how I would modify your design to get the voltage to my required level, or would that not be practical in your design?

Comment: @Shaken_U Just copying the existing driver saves you lot of trouble… couldn’t you do it that way? Seems like a simple design and if it works for your application, then I see no problem? Using a 50/60Hz transformer to step up voltage is mind-numbingly simple.

Answer (score 3):

1. Is it unreasonable to hit the valve with 275v to get the response time needed?

Since the company who makes the valve does it, it's likely not unreasonable.  They would be the ones to ask about maximum voltage and time for that type of drive scheme.

2. What is the math behind why hitting the valve with a higher voltage gets it to open faster?

The force on the solenoid is proportional to current.  Since the solenoid is inductive, we have the following equation relating voltage and current in an inductor:

$$ V=L*di/dt $$

In order to increase the current faster (the di/dt) you need a larger voltage.

3. Is a charge pump a reasonable way to create this voltage?

Depends on your input voltage available, the system requirements, the duty cycle of operation, the current and energy required, and other tradeoffs.

4. Are there any suggestions for a controller to make this easier, if a charge pump is reasonable?

I could envision a small flyback converter that charges a cap that dumps its energy into the solenoid to actuate it, but that may or may not be a good solution depending on the factors mentioned above. (And it's not strictly a charge pump.)  A more detailed design would require more information about the application and would be beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

The math is a little more complicated than just the inductance effect; solenoid force is related to current and the length of the magnetic gap.  The current is affected by the inductance, and @John D says, but as the solenoid gap closes, an effect similar to the back-EMF of a motor occurs, further resisting rapid current increase.  And, the amount of force needed to close the gap is dependent on the requirement to accelerate the moving mass.  But in any case, you know that 275 volts gets you where you want to be, so that should be your target.

The approach we use is to charge a capacitor bank.  You can find IC's which were designed for charging capacitors in flash cameras that are suited for this application.  Since your pulsewidth is less than 250 uSec, and you only need about 400 milliamperes (28 volts/70 ohms), you can calculate the capacitance you need.  This approach has the drawback that there is a delay required between each actuation to re-charge.  Since i = Cdv/dt, for a ten microfarad capacitor with i = 0.4 amps, dv/dt = 40,000 volts/sec.  So the charged capacitor would have a voltage drop of 10 volts in 250 uSec.  Pick a capacitor type with low ESR and be careful as always when handling high voltage.  It's best to go as low as you can with the capacitance, because all of the energy gets dumped into the resistance of the solenoid.

Comment: We realistically need a 20Hz switching speed, do you think that would be a viable option with this switching speed?

Comment: Capacitive discharge ignition systems use the same basic circuit as a photoflash charger.  I was involved in the preliminary design of a CDI circuit where we were planning on using a photoflash part (customer backed out, alas).  So -- yes.  You just need to use a charger circuit that can charge the cap in less than 50ms.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it unreasonable to hit the valve with 275 V to get the response time needed?

Not at all. After all, \$\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{1}{L}V(t)\$. For the current to ramp up quickly, you can either decrease the inductance or increase the voltage. Inductance is fixed by the valve design. So increasing the voltage is the only option left.

> What is the math behind why hitting the valve with a higher voltage gets it to open faster?

The valve is an inductor. Higher voltage = quicker change in current. Since the current is responsible for magnetic flux inside the valve, a certain current threshold must be reached for the valve to operate. That's why it's important that the current ramps up quickly: it must reach the "operate point" in 0.25ms.

> Is a charge pump a reasonable way to create this voltage?

No. It'll dissipate a lot of power. Remember that when a capacitor is charged from a "fixed voltage", half of the energy is wasted as heat in the resistance of the voltage source, the connecting wiring, and the series resistance of the capacitor itself. That **always** happens, no matter what you do. Charge pumps are called that because they use capacitors as energy buckets. Each time the charge is moved between capacitors at different voltages, half of the energy moved is lost.

> Are there any suggestions for a controller to make this easier, if a charge pump is reasonable?

A charge pump would be probably the hardest way to do it, given the heat dissipation and high ripple currents through the capacitors.

If you asked me to do it in an afternoon, I'd grab a 240V-to-24V transformer, drive from the 24V side with a 28V square wave through a pair of mosfets, rectify the high voltage, and use six mosfets and HV gate drivers to send that to the valve. The pulse can be generated by a non-retriggerable single shot. After the single shot expires, the valve would be then driven from 28V until it's time to turn it off. Then a negative voltage pulse would be applied to the valve. The circuitry has few gotchas and as long as you follow good practice around switching inductive loads with mosfets, it should be a straightforward job. If your time is free, the total parts cost for four valves - assuming a 28V supply available - would be maybe $100, PCB included. Of course the rest of the cost is in the know-how :)

A general block diagram of such a driver would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYBuEG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The quickest way to prototype the digital logic part - the clock generator, the non-overlapping control waveform generators, and the "boost" pulse control based on an analog voltage - would be using an Arm-based "Arduino"-like microcontroller. I'm sure even low-end devices like Arudino UNO could do it, using hard-coded low level C. But RP2040 would be a good prototyping platform, as it has enough hardware to control many valves and do much fancier tasks as well, but specifically the generation of timing pulses driven by a table and triggered by external inputs could be done very reliably with hardware resources. After configuring all the necessary DMA transfers and the PIO state machines, the software would essentially halt. Even the ADC value could be used directly for timing, since the overall timer architecture is very flexible. RP2040 DMA (and many similar DMAs) can execute many transfers in series, based on a "recipe" in memory.

The low- and high-side gate drivers would be off-the-shelf chips, unless you insist on learning how to put them together from discrete parts, which is not as simple as it seems.

Comment: So, why did you choose to use 6 different mosfets, instead of just breaking the 300v on the high side, diode protecting the 28v line, and then breaking both on the low side with another mosfet?

Comment: Because synchronous switching is generally nicer to prototype than diodes that tend to burn your fingers when you touch them :) Mosfets are cheap. 4, 6 or 12 won’t matter much if they get the job done and give flexibility to the drive waveforms. If some more inefficiency would be acceptable, you might as well use closed loop current control, and not use the 28V line directly other than to make HV.  The idea is to do it quickly. That’s how I would do it. I’m not you, and I’m not suggesting that’s the best way, only a way. You’ll learn a lot no matter how you do it.